# Jar+War против Ear

Tags: spring, java-ee

Насколько я понимаю, есть два варианта деплоя web приложения:

1. Собирать jar и war архивы в общий
       ear архив и деплоить его.
2. Просто брать jar и war архивы и
       деплоить их по одному.

Есть ли какая-то разница между ними?

Answer (score 1):

jar и war - это обычные архивы, которые создаются для разных целей и называются по разному для отличия.

1. jar - хранит ресурсы, проперти, 
       библиотеки
2. war - содержит целое веб приложение,    все что может
       понадобится для него:    jsp, html, 
       javascript
3. ear - EJB объекты

Comment: Вопрос был не в том, чем jar от war отличается, а в том, собирать их в ear или не собирать.